# Prestashop 1.6 blank page no error reporting

Tags: php, prestashop, prestashop-1.6

I have turned on error reporting and debug mode:

```
//defines.inc.php
define('_PS_MODE_DEV_', true);
@ini_set('display_errors', 'on');
define('_PS_DEBUG_SQL_', true);
```

Also i have tailed -f php_error.log, apache_error.log, mysql_error.log
Only relevant i got is:

```
[01-Dec-2014 10:12:07 America/Bogota] PHP Notice:  Trying to get property of non-object in /Users/david/Documents/Developer/Php/PuntoCompra/puntocompra/modules/posstaticblocks/ajax.php on line 9
[01-Dec-2014 10:12:07 America/Bogota] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'LIMIT 1' at line 4<br /><br /><pre>
            SELECT m.*
            FROM `puntocom_module` m
            JOIN `puntocom_module_shop` ms ON (m.`id_module` = ms.`id_module` AND ms.`id_shop` = 1)
            WHERE m.`id_module` =  LIMIT 1</pre>
  thrown in /Users/david/Documents/Developer/Php/PuntoCompra/puntocompra/classes/db/Db.php on line 635
```

I dont think this has something to do, since the front and backoffice are working fine except that when i submit or update a product **i got a blank page.** This is happening in both develpment and production environments.

Anyway here is my ajax.php

```
require_once(dirname(__FILE__).'../../../config/config.inc.php');
require_once(dirname(__FILE__).'../../../init.php');
include(dirname(__FILE__).'/posstaticblocks.php');

 $pos = new posstaticblocks();
 $name_module = $_POST['module_id'];
 $module = Module::getInstanceByName($name_module);
 $id_module = $module->id;
 $hooks = $pos->getHooksByModuleId($id_module);
 $hookArrays = array();
 foreach($hooks as $key => $hook) {
    $hookArrays[$key] = array('id_hook'=>$hook['name'], 'name' => $hook['name']);
 }
 $json = json_encode($hookArrays); 
die(json_encode($json));
```

Also i think this is not related but in my front office only in development environment i've got this:

```
 Notice: Undefined property: Possearchcategories::$_html in /Users/david/Documents/Developer/Php/PuntoCompra/puntocompra/modules/possearchcategories/possearchcategories.php on line 237
```

I have also cleared the cache.

Where else can i seek out for this problem?

Edit:
This is my url before the product update:

```
//localhost:8888/adminxxxx/index.php?controller=AdminProducts&id_product=10&updateproduct&token=019b50f16c6927fc989c8d98fa9ebbed
```

And this is after my update

```
//localhost:8888/adminxxxx/index.php?controller=AdminProducts&token=019b50f16c6927fc989c8d98fa9ebbed&id_product=10
```

I have inspected the network response and this is what firebug shows:

[image: ajax post response?]

[image: empty response]

This makes me think that ajax answer with non responding request in the ajax.php file mentioned above has the fault in this matter. It seems that there is a missing module..

Edit 2:

Turns out that when loading the products page there is the following ajax post request:

```
POST //localhost:8888/modules/posstaticblocks/ajax.php
```

With the following parameters:

```
module_id   undefined
```

And the response:

```
"[{\"id_hook\":\"displayFooter\",\"name\":\"displayFooter\"},{\"id_hook\":\"displayHome\",\"name\":\"displayHome\"},{\"id_hook\":\"displayLeftColumn\",\"name\":\"displayLeftColumn\"},{\"id_hook\":\"displayRightColumn\",\"name\":\"displayRightColumn\"},{\"id_hook\":\"displayTop\",\"name\":\"displayTop\"}]"
```

So i've done the following ***don't kill me please*** mod:

```
// /modules/poststaticblocks/ajax.php
$name_module = $_POST['module_id'];
if($name_module == "undefined")
    $name_module = "posstaticblocks";
```

And the error is gone!, but the blank page is still showing

Comment: Is this WHERE m.`id_module` =  LIMIT 1 part of your actual query? As the error tells you *"for the right syntax to use near 'LIMIT 1'"*

Comment: @Fred-ii- Exactly, that is the missing id_module that is causing the problem... i suppose.

Comment: If `WHERE m.id_module = LIMIT 1` is your actual query, you can't do that. You may have meant `WHERE m.id_module = 'something' LIMIT 1`

Comment: @Fred-ii- yes. Exactly that is what is causing that SQL exception. Now that is executed in the modules/poststaticblocks/ajax.php file in $id_module = $module->id; I think the ORM is executing that query, i got no control on that query except i can seek out the module that is making the framework do that query.

Comment: I know nothing about Prestashop. Let's see if anyone picks up on the question.

Answer (score 1):

change the line 451 in /controllers/admin/AdminModulesPositionsController.php

```
$all_modules_controllers = Dispatcher::getModuleControllers($type);
```

to

```
$all_modules_controllers = Dispatcher::getControllers($type);
```

Which seems to have eliminated the problem, without giving new problems.

So it has to be a bug in the new Prestashop ver. 1.6.0.6